# Is it possible to create an interface in a decorator?

Tags: typescript

I have some Model objects, that have a schema associated with them (the schema has some information that doesn't map well into typescript types, like default values if unset and permissions data).

So a schema looks like:

```
const PersonSchema: ModelSchema {
  attributes: { name: 'string', default: '' }, // etc
  storeData: { sql: { indexColumn: 'uid' } }
  authorizers: { update: /* snip */}
}
```

note that the types here are strings that are typenames, because this is used at runtime (and I haven't figured out how to use reflect-metadata properly yet) to do stuff like make sure you're serlializing and deserializing data properly.

and when you actually have a `Person` and get its attributes, you've got

```
interface PersonData {
  id: number | string; // some data stores use string uids, some don't
  attributes: { name: string }
}
```

So I could get something like `{ id: 42, attributes: { name: 'Arthur Dent' } }`, and the `PersonData` interface means I'm properly accessing attributes and so on.

Naturally, there's a strong correlation between the schema that fully defines the data model and the interface that defines what you get from `Model.get()`. The PersonData interface can be inferred from the PersonSchema.

Right now, I do this

```
class Model<U extends ModelData> {
  get(): Promise<U>
}
class Person extends Model<PersonData> {}
```

What I'd like to do is define a decorator that can be attached to Model classes, like so:

```
@Schema(PersonSchema) class Person extends Model {
}
```

and that would make me able to not have to define the PersonData interface, and not to have to define the return subtype of get.

I'm pretty sure this is impossible, although I'd be okay with having the return type be some kind of inferred-from-context type instead of a named interface.

Comment: There are at least 3 libraries capable of inferring interface type from the schema description: [runtypes](https://github.com/pelotom/runtypes#static-type-inference), [typebox](https://github.com/sinclairzx81/typebox) and [antireflection](https://github.com/fictitious/antireflection/blob/master/packages/antireflection/README.md) (disclaimer: the last one is mine). I don't think there is anything that will accept the format of `attributes` in your example out of the box, however.